# Weird node setup when importing .obj file

Tags: node-editor

blender noob here.
I used to pose in XPS, export as .obj, import to blender, apply textures, no problem at all.

After the 2.79 update, whenever I import a .obj file, I get this weird node setup on all meshes

[image]

I usually just deleted all the nodes from all the meshes, but lately I've been working on larger files with more objects, so it's becoming annoying.

I feel like there's something silly at work here, but I googled and found no clue, so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

That's just how the importer interprets materials that come with obj format. If there was some description of a material in the .mtl file it would construct this shader according to it.

You can replace them easily if you delete the material and make a new one. If for some reason that was not acceptable you could use Python to replace the nodes. Let's say it would be convenient for you to have standard Material Output node and a Diffuse BSDF and Glossy BSDF mix by Fresnel connected to it and you wanted to replace the nodes only for the materials that are applied to the currently selected objects. Python script would go like that:

```
import bpy

done_materials=[]

for every_object in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    try:
        for every_slot in every_object.material_slots:
            if every_slot.material not in done_materials:
                #print(every_slot.material.name)
                nodes = every_slot.material.node_tree.nodes
                links = every_slot.material.node_tree.links
                for every_node in nodes:
                    nodes.remove(every_node)
                diff = nodes.new('ShaderNodeBsdfDiffuse')   
                diff.location = (-190,100)
                gloss = nodes.new('ShaderNodeBsdfGlossy')   
                gloss.location = (-190,-20)
                mix = nodes.new('ShaderNodeMixShader')   
                mix.location = (10,95)
                Fres = nodes.new('ShaderNodeFresnel')   
                Fres.location = (-190,200)
                Fres.inputs[0].default_value=1.3
                out = nodes.new('ShaderNodeOutputMaterial')   
                out.location = (200,95)
                links.new(mix.outputs[0], out.inputs[0])
                links.new(Fres.outputs[0], mix.inputs[0])
                links.new(diff.outputs[0], mix.inputs[1])
                links.new(gloss.outputs[0], mix.inputs[2])
                done_materials.append(every_slot.material)
    except: 
        pass
```

And of course you would just need to have that pasted into a new text block in the Text Editor, select all the objects that you want processed and hit Run Script.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, and I'm terribly sorry for my late reply!

I ended up finding what I was doing 'wrong'.
I was importing the obj file with the Cycles engine selected, which creates all the above nodes for the meshes.
So what I'm doing is simply importing with the Blender internal engine selected, then switch to Cycles.
The internal engine doesn't create any node setup for the meshes, so i don't have to go through the hassle of deleting every setup for every mesh.

Anyway, big thanks for the bit of code, it's sure gonna come in handy. And again, very sorry for the late reply.